# A question about Keras embedding layer mask_zero

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using Keras with TensorFlow 2.0. I have an embedding layer which I initialize like the following:

```
embed = Embedding(len(embedding_weights), params['embedding_dim'], input_length=sequence_length, mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights],name="embedding")(model_input)
```

`embedding_weights` is a matrix of word embeddings. `embedding_weights[0]` is a row of zeros.

However, for an input = `[1,2,5,1,5, 0,0,0 ...],` the embedding layer outputs a non-zero vector for the padding zeros. Aren't these supposed to be zeros? Why is the model updating the zero vector in the embedding matrix?

Comment: The vectors are repeated for the last non-zero step of the calculation. See this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485216/how-does-mask-zero-in-keras-embedding-layer-work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does mask\_zero in Keras Embedding layer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485216/how-does-mask-zero-in-keras-embedding-layer-work)